# jQuery: replace string in an element and add it to the DOM

Tags: jquery

I want to replace a string in an element so place it again to the dom (but with the new string of course).

I have tried this:

```
var foo = $('span').toString();
var aux = foo.replace('hello', 'hola');
$('span').after($.parseHTML(aux));
```

but it doesn't work. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/252ek7wd/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the text value of span. You are converting object to string. which is incorrect. Use:

```
 var foo = $('span').text();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pjnsjaat/)**

**Update:** Preserving Div tag

```
var foo = $('div')[0].outerHTML;
var aux = foo.replace('hello', 'hola');
$('div').after(aux);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d5t7h26g/)**

Comment: Tahnks, but "hola" is not inside a div element. I want to keep the outer tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the text from the div, replace the text, then place it. Here's an example

```
var foo = $('div');
var text = foo.text();
var aux = text.replace('hello', 'hola');
$('div').after(aux);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s23x7wd8/)